# How to implement different algorithm for List in javers?

Tags: java, javers

Suppose this is my entity class.

```
class Person{
  List<Asset> assetList;
}
```

Scenario 1:

```
List<Asset> | List<Asset>

Asset1      | Asset1
Asset2      | Asset3
Asset3      |
```

Scenario 2:

```
List<Asset> | List<Asset>

Asset1      | Asset2
Asset2      | Asset1
Asset3      | Asset3
```

For the above specified scenarios, I want to run the AS_SET algorithm and in the rest of the `List<Asset>` comparison case, I want to run the LEVENSHTEIN algorithm as default while performing Diff diff = javers.compare(Person, Person2).

Is there any way to achieve in Javers?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it, but you need two instances of Javers since Javers' configuration is immutable.